# how to limit resource in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ulimit

I've posted a question about this few hours ago on Stack Overflow:

> [Linux bash inline command to execute a program and limit the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012370/Linux-bash-inline-command-to-execute-a-program-and-limit-the-resource)

As I know, to limit the resource I can use ulimit command.

But, the problem is when I set the CPU time limit 1 second, and then I want to execute another program with CPU limit 2s, the ulimit command return an error like this:

`bash: ulimit: CPU time: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted`

and absolutely my program killed in 1 second.

So, How can I make the second program running with the CPU time limit 2 seconds?

Comment: are you executing as super user?

Comment: How exactly are you running the commands?

Comment: @phoxis : nope..
@jcollie : `ulimit -t 1; ./a <input.in> ouput.out` and the second one `ulimit -t 1; ./b <input.in> output.out`

Comment: i think you need to run it as super user.

Comment: is there any way to do it not in super user? because I want to do it from php script.
thx for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my answer after a few times carefully reading about ulimit...
I found my mistake...
I had a wrong perception about soft limit and hard limit, and what I need to do is use soft limit for the command..
and I done it with `ulimit -St 1; ./a  ouput.out`
and for the second one `ulimit -St 2; ./a  ouput.out`

I'm sorry for my bad... 
wish this post would be helpful for everyone who need it...
Thanks very much..

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to give priorities to processes rather than limiting it's resources. Why don't let the process run at full power if the machine is idle?

You can use `nice` to run commands with lower or higher priority. You only need superuser access if you wish to run with higher priority.

```
$ nice [-n increment] ./a <input.in> output.out
```

You can also use `renice` to change the priority of process that are already running.

Both `nice` and `renice` can receive an optional parameter -n with an integer `(-20 <= n <= 20)`. Positive integer make the process *nicer* and use less resources, while negative integers will make it less *nice*. If no parameter is given `10` is assumed.